# How to create a Generic Bubble Sorting in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sorting, bubble-sort

I am currently working on making my own Generic Bubble Sorting which can easily sort Strings, int. Below is my Code for Normal Bubble Sorting.Can you help me out how to create a generic Method Of this?

```
public static void BubbleSorting()
{

       int Swap;
        for (int outer = Length; outer >= 1; outer--)
        {
            for (int inner = 0; inner < outer - 1; inner++)
            {
                if (array[inner] > array[inner + 1])
                {
                    Swap = array[inner];
                    array[inner] = array[inner + 1];
                    array[inner + 1] = Swap;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Display();
        }

    }
```

Comment: `if (array[inner] > array[inner + 1])` is the only important line. How would you determine whether a string is "larger than" another string?

Comment: @Matt Does the pope crap in the woods?

Comment: @bzlm: probably.... I doubt it'd be his most preferred option, but if there are no alternatives, I'd assume so.

Comment: @Matt No this IS nit mY HomeWork! I was Wondering How List.sort etc method Sort The collection. so while being interseted in that so i began working on this thing.

Comment: @Pro_Zeck: fair enough. It's not a problem to post homework, just knowing either way affects the answers you get :)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void BubbleSort<T>(T[] array, IComparer<T> comparer) {
  if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
  T Swap;
  // etc..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `IComparable` if the elements in the array implements `IComparable` you can replace

```
array[inner] > array[inner + 1]
```

with

```
array[inner].CompareTo(array[inner + 1]) > 0
```

so end up with

```
public static void BubbleSorting<T>(T[] array) where T : Icomparable
{
   for (int outer = Length; outer >= 1; outer--)
    {
        for (int inner = 0; inner < outer - 1; inner++)
        {
            if (array[inner].CompareTo(array[inner + 1]) > 0)
            {
                T Swap = array[inner];
                array[inner] = array[inner + 1];
                array[inner + 1] = Swap;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that handle nulls correctly?  I see a NullReferenceException in that inner if-statement.

Comment: It won't work and even compile. You're trying to assign to Swap variable (with type of int) value from generic array.

Comment: Now it should compile (:

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void BubbleSort<T>(T[] list) 
    { 
        BubbleSort<T>(list, Comparer<T>.Default); 
    }

    public static void BubbleSort<T>(T[] list, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        bool KeepIterating = true;
        while (KeepIterating)
        {
            KeepIterating = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length-1; i++)
            {
                T x = list[i];
                T y = list[i + 1];
                if (comparer.Compare(x,y)>0)
                {
                    list[i] = y;
                    list[i + 1] = x;
                    KeepIterating = true;

                    for (int j = 0; j < list.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",j,list[j]);
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should edit your question instead of posting your solution as an answer. :)